# Clarification on .Net version(2.0, 3.5, 1.1) COM add-in behavior with .Net 4.0 Process

Tags: c#, .net, .net-framework-version

Scenario:
An application targeting .Net 3.5 is perfectly able to add COM add-ins targeting .Net framework 1.1, 2.0 or 3.5.

As soon as the same application is migrated to target framework 4.0. Some of these add-ins started giving issues mainly with com calls, same calls works fine when application targets framework 3.5.

Using config attribute... "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"", which Enable .NET Framework 2.0 runtime activation policy for the chosen runtime, which is to bind legacy runtime activation techniques (such as the CorBindToRuntimeEx function) to the runtime chosen from the configuration file instead of capping them at CLR version 2.0. Some of these add-in earlier giving problem started working fine with target .Net 4.0.

Still some of them fail because of this attribute, and once removed those which worked because of this starts to fail.

Any suggestion to make all of these add-ins work with target framework 4.0?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense at all to use COM in this scenario, a host application that targets 4.0 should use normal .NET assembly binding.  I suppose you could hack around that by using late binding but then the 4.0 feature that allows multiple CLR versions to be loaded cannot work.  "Still some of them fail" is a hopelessly broad and unspecific diagnostic that you cannot get help with here.

Comment: Well that can not be changed as that is bounded by a specification that targets .Net 3.5, and is becoming a limitation now if at all applications needs to move to newer .Net versions. .Net really provided a bottleneck here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the detailed description, click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx). Looks like I got a case where .Net clr 2.0 loaded S x S with clr 4.0 is not working for components that needs clr 1.1.